# The URI you submitted has disallowed characters. displaying PDF file in HTML

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display a `pdf` in the `html`, but an error occurred saying *"The URI you submitted has disallowed characters".*

I tried a lot of different approaches, like changing;

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

to

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = ' ';
```

Comment: you should add all parameters which you ll send in url, dont remove it.
Try adding `,`

Comment: Hi everyone I was able to include all the parameters. 
I was able to find the error, its not on the config.php its on the controller i wasn't able to include some code in the  controller that is called in the views.. Thank you so much everyone for your urgent response I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

and ***note `&mdash` will not Work with it.***

Comment: Hello thank you for your  response. I found the error and its not in the config.php it in the controller. thank you so much I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jona happy to help :)

Comment: @jona -- Can you expand on your answer?  What was in the controller that helped you?